# Facing a problem in Java Script as a beginner

Tags: javascript, html, css

A beginner here I am facing an issue that I am building a website using HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT. But the issue is I have added play buttons (PLay songs) in the website but the actual problem is that only the first button is working instead of all.

Can anyone help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

The code is attached.

```js
burger=document.querySelector('.burger')
nav=document.querySelector('.nav')
navbarItems=document.querySelector('.navbar-items')
faPlayCircle=document.querySelector('.fa-play-circle')
 music=document.querySelector("audio")
 
  img=document.querySelector('img')



burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    navbarItems.classList.toggle('h-class')
    nav.classList.toggle('v-class')
    
})

let isplaying='false';
let playMusic=()=>{
 isplaying=true;
 music.play();
 faPlayCircle.classList.replace("fa-play-circle" ,"fa-pause")
 img.classList.add("playmusic")
};
  let pauseMusic=()=>{
    isplaying=false;
    music.pause();
    faPlayCircle.classList.replace("fa-pause","fa-play-circle")
    img.classList.remove("playmusic")
   };

  //  faPlayCircle.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  //     if(isplaying){

  //         pauseMusic();
  //     }
  //     else{
  //         playMusic();

  //     }
  //  }); 
document.querySelectorAll('.fa-play-circle', '.music','.img').forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(isplaying){

         pauseMusic();
              }
           else{
         playMusic();
            
               }

    })
  })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Encode+Sans+SC:wght@100;200;700&family=Uchen&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    font-family: 'Encode Sans SC', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Uchen', serif;

    
}
 
.homepg{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
     background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url(img/bg5.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.logo{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size:30px ;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.logo::first-letter{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 33px;
    
    
}
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    padding: 3% 2%;
    position: relative;
    


}
.navbar-items{
    flex: 1;
   text-align: right;
   margin-top: 12px;


}
.navbar-items ul{
    padding-right: 20px;

}
.navbar-items ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-items ul li a{
    padding: 0px 48px;
    color:white ;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar-items ul li a:hover{
    color: purple;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}
.content{
    width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    
}
.heading{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}
.heading::first-letter{
     font-size: 4em;
     color: purple;
     float: left;
     line-height: 0.8px;
}
.para{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

}
.btn{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:purple;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    padding: 11px 22px ;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: purple;
    transition: 1s;
    color: white;
}
.burger{
    display: none;


}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .navbar-items{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: purple;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-top: 0;
        transition: all 1s ease-out;
        
    }
    .navbar-items ul li{
        display: block;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul{
        padding-top: 48%;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul li a{
        color: black;
        padding: 0px 30px;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul li a:hover{
        border: 2px solid white;
        color: white;
        
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        right: 7%;
        top: 5px;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
 .h-class{
        height: 100vh;
        opacity: 0;
    }

     .v-class{
        opacity: 0;
    } 
    .heading{
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    .para{
        font-size: 12px;
    
    }
} 
/* --------artists-section--------- */
.row{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.top-artists{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3%;

}
.top-artists h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.top-artists h1:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.artists{
    flex-basis: 34%;
}
.artists img{
 width: 60%;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.artists-col{
    padding: 12px 14px;
}
.artists-col h3{
     padding-bottom: 3px;
     font-size: 20px;
}
.artists-col p{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #fff3f3;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: 12px 13px;
    color: rgb(97, 57, 57);
    
}
.artists-col p:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 6, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* -----------icons-section---------- */
.icons{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 22px 0px;
    
    
}
.icons .fa{
    padding: 9px 4px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: purple;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
.icons .fa:hover{
    color: white;
}
.icons-col{
    top: 200px;
    left: 0%;
    width:76px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .row{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .artists-col {
    padding: 0px;
    }
    .artists{
        padding-bottom: 29px;
    }
}

/* -----------india-artists-------- */
.artists-india{
 flex-basis: 34%;
 margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.artists-india img{
    width: 60%;
    border-radius:10px ;

}

/* ----------------footer-section---------------- */
.footer-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: black;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%,100% 50%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 20%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    
}
.comment{
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 13%; 
    position: relative;
    
}
.comment h1{
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .comment-sec input,.comment-sec textarea{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid purple;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    

}
.btn1{
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}
.btn1:hover{
background-color: white;
color: purple;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 1s;
}
.footer{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5%;
    
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .comment-sec input,textarea{
        width: 90%;
    } 
    .btn1{
        padding: 8px 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
    } 
    .comment h1{
        padding-top: 10%;
    
    } 
    .comment{
    
        color: white;
        padding-top: 30%;
        z-index: 1;
        
    }

}

/* -------------------BLOG-SEC--------------- */
.subpages{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)) ,url(img/bg7.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.subcontent h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;

}
.subcontent h1:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.footer1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
.blog-content{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.blog-content img{
    width: 100%;
}
.blog-content p{
    color: #777;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.blog-content h1{
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 18%;
}
.blog-sec{
    flex-basis: 58%;

}
.blog img{
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 12%;
 border-radius: 5%;
}
.blog img:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .subcontent h1{
    
        margin-top: 37%;
        font-size: 46px;
        font-weight: 700;
    
    } 
}
/* --------------------contact-section---------------- */
.contact-col{
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.contact{
  width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 border-radius: 12px;
}
.contact-sec{
    padding:  40px 50px;
    border: 2px solid plum;
    

}
 .contact-sec input, .contact-sec textarea{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border:2px solid #777;
}
.contact-row{
    flex-basis: 49%;
}
.icons1{
   margin-top: 20%;
   padding-left: 5%;
}
.icons1 .fa{
    font-size: 33px;
    
}
.icons1 .fa:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
/* -----------music-section----------- */
.music{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.music-col{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border: 2px solid rgb(141, 134, 124);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 0px 1rem 0px 1rem;
    background-color: lavender;
}
.music-col h3{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#912b63;
}
.music-col p{
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}
.music-img{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.music-img img{
    width: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    
}
.music-play{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.music-play .fas{
     font-size: 34px;
     padding: 2rem;
    
}

.playmusic{
    animation: rotateimg 4s linear  infinite ;
}
@keyframes rotateimg{
    from{ transform: rotate(0deg);

    }
    to{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>M-Rock --Music Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="homepg subpages">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">M-ROCK</div>
            <nav class="navbar-items h-class">
             <ul class="nav v-class">
                 <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>     
                 <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>     
               <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>  
               <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>  
             </ul>
        
            </nav>
            <div class="burger">&#9776</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent contact-col">
            <h1>Songs</h1>
            
        </div>
    </Section>

   
    <section class="music">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="music-col">
            <h3>PEHLI DAFA</h3>
            <p>ATIF ASLAM</p>
            <div class="music-img">
                <img class ='img'src="img/music1.jpg "  alt="">
            </div>
              <audio class= 'audio'src="img/music1.mp3" ></audio>
                <div class="music-play">
                
                    <i class="fas fa-stop"  title="stop"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-play-circle"   title="play"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-volume-up" title="volume"></i>
                
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="music-col">
              <h3>NAINA</h3>
              <P>ARIJIT SINGH</P>
              <div class="music-img">

                <img class ='img'src="img/music2.jpg"  alt="">
            </div>
            <audio class= 'audio' src="img/music2.mp3" ></audio>
            <div class="music-play">

                <i class="fas fa-stop"  title="stop"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-play-circle play" title="play"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-volume-up" title="volume"></i>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="music-col">
            <h3>CHANNA MERAYA</h3>
            <p>ARIJIT SINGH</p>
            <div class="music-img">

                <img class ='img'src="img/music3.jpg"  alt="">
            </div>
            <audio class= 'audio' src="img/music3.mp3" ></audio>

            <div class="music-play">
                <i class="fas fa-stop" title="stop"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-play-circle play"title="play"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-volume-up"  title="volume"></i>
            </div>

        </div>
              
        </div>
    </section>
     
  <Section class="footer1">
        <p>Copyright @ 2021-2025 by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Among other things that are wrong in your code, you select only one play button `faPlayCircle=document.querySelector('.fa-play-circle')` . If you want to select all play buttons use `querySelectorAll` and loop through them and select the 'audio' element depending on that. I see you use querySelector everywhere even when wanting to select multiple elements.

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks for responding, can you please let me know how to do that. I will be thankful to you

Comment: Well i see in your code that you have a forEach on a querySelectorAll . Use the same logic. And just read the docs on how to use querySelectorAll , how to loop over the result and how to select an element depending on another element ( you find tons of questions about this here on SO )

Comment: I have used queryslectorAll but it says "MUSIC.PLAY Error" . :(

Comment: I suggest you take it easy. Javscript isn't learned over night. Start with some basics. Then build your way to more advanced stuff . Read a lot of docs. Learn how to ask 'google' your questions and there is an answer for almost everything out there. Patience and hard work. That's the way to go. If you want to get help here, try to separate your code and ask a specific question for a specific problem. Otherwise ( as you can see ) noone spends his time to debug a whole bunch of code. Try to separate the problem and come back with a better formatted question.

Comment: Instead of making those buttons yourself you can simply use the controls attribute in order to get audio controls. Instead of this `<audio class= 'audio' src="img/music3.mp3" ></audio>` make it `<audio class= 'audio' src="img/music3.mp3"  controls />` simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```js
// Initialize variables
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
let nav = document.querySelector('.nav')
let navbarItems = document.querySelector('.navbar-items')

/* Music  */
let musicSection = document.getElementById("music");
var isplaying = true;


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarItems.classList.toggle('h-class')
    nav.classList.toggle('v-class')

})

musicSection.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
// Notice This function is only for play button , not for stop or sound button 
    let TargetedElement = event.target;
    // Select Play Button Using Class "Options"
    if (TargetedElement.className.includes('Options')) {

        let selected = document.querySelector('.Selected');
        // This will be the flag for the selected element.

        let img = TargetedElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".img")
        
        // target the Music using previousElementSibling
        let music = TargetedElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
        var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
        let playElements = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-pause");
        // set loop for pause
        for (let i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
            // pause all sounds            
            if (sounds[i].play) sounds[i].pause();

            // changing pause icons to play 
            if (playElements[i]) playElements[i].classList.replace("fa-pause", "fa-play-circle")
        }
        // checking the condition for playing 
        if (isplaying) {            
            music.play();
            isplaying = false;
            TargetedElement.classList.replace("fa-play-circle", "fa-pause")
            img.classList.add("playmusic");
        }
        else{
            music.pause();
            isplaying = true;
            TargetedElement.classList.replace("fa-pause", "fa-play-circle")
            img.classList.remove("playmusic")
        }

        // Remove the selected element 
        if (selected) selected.classList.remove('Selected');
        // Here we're removing the element that was selected before. 

        TargetedElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('Selected');
        // Adding a class to the targeted element so we will able to select it later

    }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Encode+Sans+SC:wght@100;200;700&family=Uchen&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    font-family: 'Encode Sans SC', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Uchen', serif;

    
}
 
.homepg{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
     background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url(img/bg5.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.logo{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size:30px ;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.logo::first-letter{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 33px;
    
    
}
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    padding: 3% 2%;
    position: relative;
    


}
.navbar-items{
    flex: 1;
   text-align: right;
   margin-top: 12px;


}
.navbar-items ul{
    padding-right: 20px;

}
.navbar-items ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-items ul li a{
    padding: 0px 48px;
    color:white ;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar-items ul li a:hover{
    color: purple;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}
.content{
    width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    
}
.heading{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}
.heading::first-letter{
     font-size: 4em;
     color: purple;
     float: left;
     line-height: 0.8px;
}
.para{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

}
.btn{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:purple;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    padding: 11px 22px ;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: purple;
    transition: 1s;
    color: white;
}
.burger{
    display: none;


}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .navbar-items{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: purple;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-top: 0;
        transition: all 1s ease-out;
        
    }
    .navbar-items ul li{
        display: block;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul{
        padding-top: 48%;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul li a{
        color: black;
        padding: 0px 30px;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .navbar-items ul li a:hover{
        border: 2px solid white;
        color: white;
        
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        right: 7%;
        top: 5px;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
 .h-class{
        height: 100vh;
        opacity: 0;
    }

     .v-class{
        opacity: 0;
    } 
    .heading{
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    .para{
        font-size: 12px;
    
    }
} 
/* --------artists-section--------- */
.row{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.top-artists{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3%;

}
.top-artists h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.top-artists h1:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.artists{
    flex-basis: 34%;
}
.artists img{
 width: 60%;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.artists-col{
    padding: 12px 14px;
}
.artists-col h3{
     padding-bottom: 3px;
     font-size: 20px;
}
.artists-col p{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #fff3f3;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: 12px 13px;
    color: rgb(97, 57, 57);
    
}
.artists-col p:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 6, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* -----------icons-section---------- */
.icons{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 22px 0px;
    
    
}
.icons .fa{
    padding: 9px 4px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: purple;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
.icons .fa:hover{
    color: white;
}
.icons-col{
    top: 200px;
    left: 0%;
    width:76px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .row{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .artists-col {
    padding: 0px;
    }
    .artists{
        padding-bottom: 29px;
    }
}

/* -----------india-artists-------- */
.artists-india{
 flex-basis: 34%;
 margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.artists-india img{
    width: 60%;
    border-radius:10px ;

}

/* ----------------footer-section---------------- */
.footer-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: black;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%,100% 50%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 20%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    
}
.comment{
    width: 70%;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 13%; 
    position: relative;
    
}
.comment h1{
    padding-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .comment-sec input,.comment-sec textarea{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid purple;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    

}
.btn1{
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}
.btn1:hover{
background-color: white;
color: purple;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 1s;
}
.footer{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5%;
    
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .comment-sec input,textarea{
        width: 90%;
    } 
    .btn1{
        padding: 8px 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
    } 
    .comment h1{
        padding-top: 10%;
    
    } 
    .comment{
    
        color: white;
        padding-top: 30%;
        z-index: 1;
        
    }

}

/* -------------------BLOG-SEC--------------- */
.subpages{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)) ,url(img/bg7.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.subcontent h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;

}
.subcontent h1:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.footer1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
.blog-content{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.blog-content img{
    width: 100%;
}
.blog-content p{
    color: #777;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.blog-content h1{
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 18%;
}
.blog-sec{
    flex-basis: 58%;

}
.blog img{
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 12%;
 border-radius: 5%;
}
.blog img:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .subcontent h1{
    
        margin-top: 37%;
        font-size: 46px;
        font-weight: 700;
    
    } 
}
/* --------------------contact-section---------------- */
.contact-col{
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.contact{
  width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 border-radius: 12px;
}
.contact-sec{
    padding:  40px 50px;
    border: 2px solid plum;
    

}
 .contact-sec input, .contact-sec textarea{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border:2px solid #777;
}
.contact-row{
    flex-basis: 49%;
}
.icons1{
   margin-top: 20%;
   padding-left: 5%;
}
.icons1 .fa{
    font-size: 33px;
    
}
.icons1 .fa:hover{
    color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
/* -----------music-section----------- */

#music{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.music-col{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border: 2px solid rgb(141, 134, 124);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 0px 1rem 0px 1rem;
    background-color: lavender;
}
.Selected{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.music-col h3{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#912b63;
}
.music-col p{
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}
.music-img{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.music-img img{
    width: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    
}
.music-play{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.music-play .fas{
     font-size: 34px;
     padding: 2rem;
    
}

.playmusic{
    animation: rotateimg 4s linear  infinite ;
}
@keyframes rotateimg{
    from{ transform: rotate(0deg);

    }
    to{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>M-Rock --Music Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="homepg subpages">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">M-ROCK</div>
            <nav class="navbar-items h-class">
             <ul class="nav v-class">
                 <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>     
                 <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>     
               <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>  
               <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>  
             </ul>
        
            </nav>
            <div class="burger">&#9776</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent contact-col">
            <h1>Songs</h1>
            
        </div>
    </Section>

   
    <section id="music">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="music-col">
            <h3>PEHLI DAFA</h3>
            <p>ATIF ASLAM</p>
            <div class="music-img">
                <img class ='img'src="img/music1.jpg "  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="music-play">
                    <audio class= 'audio'src="img/music1.mp3" ></audio>
                
                    <i class="fas fa-stop playOpt"  title="stop"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-play-circle playOpt Options"   title="play"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-volume-up playOpt" title="volume"></i>
                
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="music-col">
              <h3>NAINA</h3>
              <P>ARIJIT SINGH</P>
              <div class="music-img">

                <img class ='img'src="img/music2.jpg"  alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="music-play">
                <audio class= 'audio' src="img/music2.mp3" ></audio>

                <i class="fas fa-stop"  title="stop"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-play-circle play Options" title="play"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-volume-up" title="volume"></i>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="music-col">
            <h3>CHANNA MERAYA</h3>
            <p>ARIJIT SINGH</p>
            <div class="music-img">
                <img class ='img'src="img/music3.jpg"  alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="music-play">
                <audio class= 'audio' src="img/music3.mp3" ></audio>
                <i class="fas fa-stop" title="stop"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-play-circle play Options"title="play"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-volume-up"  title="volume"></i>
            </div>

        </div>
              
        </div>
    </section>
     
  <Section class="footer1">
        <p>Copyright @ 2021-2025 by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man it really works, can you please identify my mistakes it will mean alot